# Slack unable to start - Bad RIP value

Tags: snap, slack

Slack would not start all of a sudden.  Slack was installed using Snap.

`dmesg`:

```
[63983.140086] ThreadPoolForeg[58617]: segfault at 34d0 ip 00000000000034d0 sp 00007fdb3e23ce08 error 14
[63983.140096] Code: Bad RIP value.
[63983.375855] traps: Chrome_IOThread[58504] trap int3 ip:55c2908ba1c4 sp:7f0ec54347e0 error:0 in slack[55c28e42e000+5caf000]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues with Slack launching after an upgrade, with what looks like the same error

```
Jul 11 16:45:43 samloyd kernel: [171452.625726] traps: Chrome_IOThread[114914] trap int3 ip:56465285b1c4 sp:7f543c1797e0 error:0 in slack[5646503cf000+5caf000]
```

Reverting to 4.4.3 fixed it.

Comment: Reverting is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Followed guidance in [this article on the snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/slack-4-7-0-sefgault-ubuntu-18-04/18708), and reverted snap.

```
sudo snap revert slack
```

Reverted slack to

```
slack reverted to 4.4.3
```

Slack was able to start after being reverted.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround worked for me using latest Slack 4.7.0 (which was causing the issue at first place):

Open terminal and run snap shell:

`snap run --shell slack`

then execute slack binary:

`$SNAP/usr/lib/slack/slack`

Source:
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/slack-4-7-0-sefgault-ubuntu-18-04/18708/3

So the SEGFAULT is caused by `--no-sandbox` flag in command argument list.

EDIT: Ubuntu snap has updated so now on Slack 4.8.0 there's no issue with startup.